# Anyone have any performance tips for SharePoint Enterprise Search?

Tags: search, performance

The first search in our Search Central (Enterprise Search) is very slow (in the range 10-20 s). Is this how it should be, any hints for speeding this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give us something we can work with, like:

1. Farm topology
2. Query topology
3. Crawl topology
4. Number and size of your index partions
5. Number and size of your content sources

In addion to that you could tell us what the search administration reports says. You can find them in the Central Administration -> Monitoring -> View administrative reports -> Search administration reports.

Comment: 1. Our setup is one shared enterprise farm (ES farm) containing the Search Service Application, this farm is shared between a few systems. Our farm consumes Search Service Application from this ES farm. Our farm is setup with about 5 physical WFE servers. 

2,3. We have a two columns and two rows setup. The first row running the query components and storing the indices. 

4. 2 index partions. One with 2m and 2nd with 1m. (Thats what it says on the environment drawing, I do not have access to the ES environment.) 

5. Number of content sources I am not sure about, it is scaled for 20M

Comment: That seems to be a nice setup. 

(1) Let's go for the search administration reports: What do they tell about your search performance?

(2) Check you search result page with the developer dashboard to identify the "time killer". You can activate it via PowerShell or STSADM (stsadm -o setproperty -pn developer-dashboard -pv ondemand)

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried out the developer dashboard on the search page. I found the "Time killer" to be the refiners. A little more research revealed that the Accuracy Index was set to 500. When changed to the default of 50 the execution time was reduced from >10 to 1 second. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

10 to 20 seconds per search?

That is NOT how it should be. Even on slow hardware you should be able to get sub second results.

The first thing to do is check the Query latency reports in Central Admin. Here you will see how long it takes and where your bottle necks are. To improve search time there are several things you can do with SharePoint but really you need to find out what part is causing the delay.

Here are some hints:

- Partition your index into several
  partitions across servers.
- Add a query server.
- Check that you haven't got some
  strange customization on the
  result page that is causing the
  page to hesitthat is returning the
  slow results, but the redering of
  the result pageate. This is
  common. It may not be the search engine at all.

Robert
www.prosharepointsearch.com

Comment: It is only the first search or if you wait some time between searches, then it will be really slow.